# Root for Xperia Z3 D6616

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, root-access, sony-xperia-z3

Does anyone know if there is a working root for the Sony Xperia Z3 D6616 (T-Mobile)? I just got upgraded to 5.0.2 but the battery life is awful now.

I know the biggest hurdle is that T-Mobile has locked the bootloader. I have tried giefroot, towelroot, and some other solution that involved sideloading the adb drivers but I can't seem to get anything to work. In addition, I would need to back up the DRM keys so I dont break any of the Sony apps I want to keep (camera apps).

Build No: 23.1.C.0.385

Answer (score -2):

kingroot 4.1

http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/one-click-root-tool-android-2-x-5-0-t3107461

if you want to remove king user and replace it with super su

follow these steps

http://www.w0lfdroid.com/2015/05/How-to-Remove-Replace-KingUser-KingRoot-with-SuperSU.html

install [dual recovery by nut's](http://nut.xperia-files.com/?ql=1e8730b7621b28cd3bef728cd8956ae2fee8e27b) (twrp,cmw,philz) using windows pc/make sure you are up to date with the drivers for xperia z3

Comment: Kingroot did not work. Desktop app did not work either. http://i.imgur.com/kKlolUx.png